# Как отследить удаление точки полигона в Yandex Maps JS-API

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

В режиме редактирования полигона пользователь может удалить вершину или внутренний контур. Однако у объекта `geometryEditor.Polygon` отсутствуют события типа `beforevertexdelete` или `vertexdeleteend`. В связи с этим я не имею возможности отследить изменение полигона при удалении точек.

Может быть, это можно отследить каким-то другим способом?

Comment: А что вы хотите сделать, зачем вам эти события? Событие "change" изменение геометрии объекта вам не подходит?

Comment: Не совсем. Нужно по-разному реагировать на начало редактирования контура и на его завершение. Но для удаления, спасибо @denis-stepanov , подходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myPolygon.geometry.events.add('change', function (event) {
    var oldCoordinates = event.get('oldCoordinates');
    var newCoordinates = event.get('newCoordinates');
});
```

Можно отслеживать изменение координат и самостоятельно определять, удалилась ли точка

Comment: Спасибо. Сравнения длин контуров оказалось достаточно.

Answer (score 1):

В итоге - вот получившийся код, отслеживающий (кажется) все изменения контура:

```
        var stateMonitor = new ymaps.Monitor(myPolygon.editor.state);
        // при завершении рисования новых точек полигона фильтруем метки
        stateMonitor.add('drawing',function(newValue){
            if(!newValue){
                RemoveMarkersOutsidePolygon(myPolygon.geometry);
            }
        });
        // Перед смещением точек полигона показываем все метки
        myPolygon.editor.events.add(['vertexdragstart', 'edgedragstart', 'vertexdraw'], function(event) {
            ShowAllMarkers(myMap);
        });
        // Перед смещением полигона показываем все метки
        myPolygon.events.add(['dragstart'], function(event) {
            ShowAllMarkers(myMap);
        });
        // После смещения точки полигона фильтруем метки
        myPolygon.editor.events.add(['edgedragend', 'vertexdragend', 'vertexadd'], function(event) {
            RemoveMarkersOutsidePolygon(event.get('target').geometry);
        });
        // После смещения полигона фильтруем метки
        myPolygon.events.add(['dragend'], function(event) {
            RemoveMarkersOutsidePolygon(event.get('target').geometry);
        });
        // После удаления точки или внутреннего контура полигона фильтруем метки
        myPolygon.geometry.events.add('change', function(event) {
            var oldCoordinates = event.get('oldCoordinates');
            var newCoordinates = event.get('newCoordinates');
            if(oldCoordinates.length > newCoordinates.length){
                // удалён внутренний контур
                RemoveMarkersOutsidePolygon(event.get('target'));
                return;
            }
            var len = Math.min(oldCoordinates.length, newCoordinates.length);
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                if (oldCoordinates[i].length > newCoordinates[i].length) {
                    // удалена точка контура
                    RemoveMarkersOutsidePolygon(event.get('target'));
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
```